# NotSerializableException trying to use JsonCredentials to query BigTable from Apache Beam

Tags: apache-beam, google-cloud-bigtable

I'm trying to connect to Google BigTable using:

```
 BigtableOptions.Builder bigTableOptions = new BigtableOptions.Builder()
            .setProjectId(options.getProjectId())
            .setInstanceId(options.getInstanceId())
            .setCredentialOptions(
                    CredentialOptions.jsonCredentials(
                                    new FileInputStream(systemResource.toFile())
                    ));
```

However, I'm getting:

```
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: java.io.FileInputStream
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1184)
```

I've tried with 
 2.1.0-SNAPSHOT
and
 2.0.0.

Has anyone else hit this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you need a different credential object for Dataflow and Cloud Bigtable?  By default, the Cloud Bigtable credentials are the same as the Dataflow credentials.

Comment: Works okay when I don't specify the credentials, but was curious to see whether I could explicitly use a "service user".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing this:

```
// Load the keyfile
final String keyFile = "service-account-keyfile.json"
final Path path = Paths.get(ClassLoader.getSystemResource(keyFile).getPath());
// Load and Convert key to a CredentialOptions object
final GoogleCredentials credentials = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(Files.newInputStream(path))
                .createScoped(Lists.newArrayList("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"));
final CredentialOptions bigTableCredentials = CredentialOptions.credential(credentials);

//Use the credentials
final BigtableOptions bigtableOptions =
            new BigtableOptions.Builder()
                    .setCredentialOptions(bigTableCredentials)
```